# Serbia Mobile Telephone Regex

Tags: php, regex, mobile, numbers

I am looking for editing my serbia Mobile Telephone  Regex.
Mobile Number begin with 
60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 677, 678
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Serbia#Mobile_telephony

What can be the right regex for nine digits number of above pattern with or without space or comma and with or without international code +381

Looking for something  better than **(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{3}**

Comment: You could at least set up some test cases. What do those 9-digit numbers look like?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the mobile number is of 10 digit without country code.
If not, change the values of `\d{8} and \d{7}` accordingly.
That is if length is `X`, put `\d{X-2}` and `\d{X-3}`

```js
 //Mobile Number begin with 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 677, 678
    // +381

    var re = /^(\+381)?(\s|-)?6(([0-6]|[8-9])\d{8}|(77|78)\d{7}){1}$/
    console.log(re.test('+381-6812345678')); // hyphen
    console.log(re.test('+381 6812345678')); // space
    console.log(re.test('+3816812345678')); // without seperator
    console.log(re.test('+381-7812345678')); //start with 7->false
    console.log(re.test('+381-6772345678')); //start in 677->true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working regex covering all Serbian mobile phone operators and variants (as of December 2023):

```php
<?php
$pattern = '/^(\+3816|06)(([0-6]|[8-9])\d{6,7}|(77|78)\d{5,6})$/';

$phoneNumbers = [
    '+381601234567',
    '061234567',
    '+38160212345',
    '063123',      
    '+381777777777',
    '066008374',
    '064abcdef',    
    '+3816812345678',
    '0693123400',
    '0677111111',
    '0641344830',
    '0691234'        
];

foreach ($phoneNumbers as $phoneNumber) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $phoneNumber)) {
        echo "✅ " . $phoneNumber . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "❌ " . $phoneNumber . "\n";
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
✅ +381601234567
✅ 061234567
✅ +38160212345
❌ 063123 
❌ +381777777777 
✅ 066008374
❌ 064abcdef 
❌ +3816812345678 
✅ 0693123400
✅ 0677111111
✅ 0641344830
❌ 0691234
```

The regex accepts both 06XXXXXXXX and +3816XXXXXXXX formats.

You can test it here: [onlinephp.io snippet](https://fsl.onl/ONQGM)